# Using Powerpoint, how do I curve text to "bend" with the circumference of a sphere?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I'm creating a powerpoint deck.  There seems to be only one kind of text box -- linear and rectangular.  How do I create a text box that "bends" with the circumference of a sphere?

Answer (score 3):

Using [WordArt](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/powerpoint-help/use-wordart-to-produce-special-text-effects-HA001132751.aspx)

It's Office version specific but here's a general walkthrough:

Select your textbox, go to the Format tab at the top, look for the *Text Effects* pulldown menu, then to *Transform* where you'll see all the basic options.

Once you've selected an option you can scale the text box and change the curve to customize the look.

Comment: I wish I could attach a slide showing you the options available when I...1) click on the text box and, 2) pull down the Format tab and select "Text Box" in my version of PPT.  The option "Text Effects" or "Transform" do not show up anywhere.

Comment: On the Format tab, Word Art Styles group, pull down Text Effects, choose Transform and go to town.